# Why have a Array Empty and Error in swift4?

Tags: arrays, swift

I've spent a few hours trying to get a fetch to work in my film sheet. I need to open film's View of my colectionview Items. I could follow different guide and post but it always give me an empty array.  I'm newbie, sorry for my question but I need your help.

Here's my code:

```
var taskArrayScheda : NewFilm?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.fetchData()

if(self.taskArrayScheda != nil) {

let schedaOk = taskArrayScheda
mostraDatiNellaScheda(schedaOk!)

} else { print("errore array vuoto") }


}

func mostraDatiNellaScheda(_ sched:NewFilm) {

// get title
titoloScheda.text = sched.titolo
}

func fetchData() {
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "NewFilm")

do {
taskArrayScheda = try context.fetch(NewAnime.fetchRequest())
ERROR ::::: Cannot assign value of type '[Any]' to type 'NewFilm?'

} catch {
print(error)
}
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but why do you create two different fetch requests? By the way the used one doesn't match the type of the property (beside the array issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetch()` returns an array. But currently you assign the `fetch()` result to the single object `var taskArrayScheda`.

You'll need something like:

```
var taskArrayScheda: [NewFilm]?
```

Then you should do:

```
taskArrayScheda = try context.fetch(NewAnime.fetchRequest()) as? [NewFilm]
```

I assume here that `NewAnime` is a subclass of `NewFilm`, which seems to make sense looking at these two class names.

Comment: so I can change with 
    `code` var taskArray = [NewFilm]()

Comment: @peg101 Yes, if you want to define a `NewAnime` array variable and set it to an empty array at the same time.

Comment: ok now I have error in this Func
     func mostraDatiNellaScheda(_ sched:[NewFilm]) {
        
    titoloScheda.text = sched.titolo
    **Value of type '[NewAnime]' has no member 'titolo'**
    }

Comment: NewFilm is my Entity

Comment: @peg101 `shed` is an array of `NewFilm`. So you must select one of the elements with something like `if let film = sched.first { titoloScheda.text = film.titolo }`